Remove a specified element from the produced array of class objects
I want to remove a certain element from the created array of class objects. The code is provided below here.
DbParameter[] Parameters =
{
    new DbParameter { Parameter = "ExamYear", Value = ExamYear },
    new DbParameter { Parameter = "Gender", Value = Gender },
    new DbParameter { Parameter = "Regid", Value = Regid },
    new DbParameter { Parameter = "Examtype", Value = Examtype }
};


How to remove an element like that. Parameters.Remove(3);?
After eliminating the fourth element, how do I achieve the result as shown in the code below?
DbParameter[] Parameters =
{
    new DbParameter { Parameter = "ExamYear", Value = ExamYear },
    new DbParameter { Parameter = "Gender", Value = Gender },
    new DbParameter { Parameter = "Regid", Value = Regid }
};


Does this answer your question? C# Adding and Removing elements to an array with an existing size

Does this answer your question? Remove element of a regular array

You can use List<DbParameter> in order to easily remove an element and then convert List<DbParameter> back to an array if needed.
First create class that holds Parameter and value like below :
public class DbParameter  
{
    public string Parameter { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

And then use it like below:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


public class DbParameter  
{
    public string Parameter { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}



public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DbParameter[] parameters =
        {
            new DbParameter { Parameter = "ExamYear", Value = "2023" },
            new DbParameter { Parameter = "Gender", Value = "Male" },
            new DbParameter { Parameter = "Regid", Value = "12345" },
            new DbParameter { Parameter = "Examtype", Value = "Final" }
        };

        
        List<DbParameter> parameterValueList = parameters.ToList();             
        parameterValueList .RemoveAt(3); // Remove the fourth element (index 3)                
        parameters = parameterValueList .ToArray(); // Convert back to array if necessary

        
        foreach (var param in parameters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Parameter: {param.Parameter}, Value: {param.Value}"); // Print values for viewing purpose
        }
    }
}


Refer the working sample here


great explanation @Selaka Nanayakkara
